# using rioxarrays plot in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, rioxarray

Using the method print in pycharms jupyter notebooks will raised `TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple`, but when calling a cell afterwards the result will be ploted nevertheless.

But the representation is upside down!

Stack trace:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-4-0697d35c68b7> in <module>
----> 1 v.sel(band=1).plot()
      2 

~\anaconda3\envs\ENDUP_SOL\lib\site-packages\xarray\plot\plot.py in __call__(self, **kwargs)
    442 
    443     def __call__(self, **kwargs):
--> 444         return plot(self._da, **kwargs)
    445 
    446     # we can't use functools.wraps here since that also modifies the name / qualname

~\anaconda3\envs\ENDUP_SOL\lib\site-packages\xarray\plot\plot.py in plot(darray, row, col, col_wrap, ax, hue, rtol, subplot_kws, **kwargs)
    195     kwargs["ax"] = ax
    196 
--> 197     return plotfunc(darray, **kwargs)
    198 
    199 

~\anaconda3\envs\ENDUP_SOL\lib\site-packages\xarray\plot\plot.py in newplotfunc(darray, x, y, figsize, size, aspect, ax, row, col, col_wrap, xincrease, yincrease, add_colorbar, add_labels, vmin, vmax, cmap, center, robust, extend, levels, infer_intervals, colors, subplot_kws, cbar_ax, cbar_kwargs, xscale, yscale, xticks, yticks, xlim, ylim, norm, **kwargs)
    764         if add_colorbar:
    765             if add_labels and "label" not in cbar_kwargs:
--> 766                 cbar_kwargs["label"] = label_from_attrs(darray)
    767             cbar = _add_colorbar(primitive, ax, cbar_ax, cbar_kwargs, cmap_params)
    768         elif cbar_ax is not None or cbar_kwargs:

~\anaconda3\envs\ENDUP_SOL\lib\site-packages\xarray\plot\utils.py in label_from_attrs(da, extra)
    466         units = ""
    467 
--> 468     return "\n".join(textwrap.wrap(name + extra + units, 30))
    469 
    470 

TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple
```

using: `v.sel(band=1).squeeze().plot.imshow()` instead of `v.sel(band=1).plot()`

still raises the error, but a) now cell call below is needed anymore, b) orientation is correct!

Update:
Code:

```
from rioxarray import open_rasterio
from geopandas import read_file, clip
import numpy as np
from pandas import read_csv
from pathlib import Path
%matplotlib inline

#%%

s2_path = r"path_to.tif"
v = open_rasterio(s2_path)
v.sel(band=1).squeeze().plot.imshow()
```

More precise error description: Normal raster can be plotted. That behavior happens ony for data that I write as DataSet and open as DataArray!?!

Comment: Are you able to provide a code example?

Comment: Hi, I edited the question. So that it hopefully, includes that information you need to reproduce the error!?!